# How do I save my print statement in a list? Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing

How do I save my print statement in a list?

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(len(values)):
        print (values[0]+values[i])+values[j]
```

Comment: Why not just add the values directly to a list?

Comment: I think that's what he's asking.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use print if you wanted to add values to a list. Just add them to a list *directly*:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(len(values)):
        result.append(values[0] + values[i] + values[j])
```

You can loop over `values` *directly* here:

```
result = []
for i in values:
    for j in values:
        result.append(values[0] + i + j)
```

which can be combined into a list comprehension:

```
result = [values[0] + i + j for i in values for j in values]
```

Comment: Is there a reason to keep the parentheses around `values[0] + i` given that addition is left-associative?

Comment: @NPE: there isn't really, no. I kept them only to give the OP something to recognise. I've removed them now.

Comment: Can I do the same with the keys? :-)

Comment: @Babe: What do you mean by *keys* here? You appear to have a sequence (a string, list, or tuple or similar) here in `values`, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable to store the result,

```
result = []
for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(len(values)):
        res = (values[0]+values[i])+values[j]
        print res
        result.append(res)
```

or do the following to slightly optimize code above:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(len(values)):
        result.append((values[0]+values[i])+values[j])
        print result[-1]
```

Better still, you can use a list comprehension to simplify this and create the end `result`:

```
result = [values[0] + i + j for i in values for j in values]
```

You can of course then print these later using a simple

```
for res in result:
    print res
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
results = [values[0] + val_i + val_j for val_i in values for val_j in values]
```